# Variable modification in a child process

Tags: c, process, fork, waitpid

I am working on Bryant and O'Hallaron's `Computer Systems, A Programmer's Perspective`. Exercise 8.16 asks for the output of a program like (I changed it because they use a header file you can download on their website):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int counter = 1;

int main()
{
    if (fork() == 0){
        counter--;
        exit(0);
    }

    else{
        Wait(NULL);
        printf("counter = %d\n", ++counter);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

I answered "counter = 1" because the parent process waits for its children to terminate and then increments counter. But the child first decrements it. However, when I tested the program, I found that the correct answer was "counter = 2". Is the variable "counter" different in the child and in the parent process? If not, then why is the answer 2?

Comment: The memory of the parent process is copied to make the child process, so no, the two processes don't share `counter`.

Comment: "Is the variable 'counter' different in the child?" - yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parent process starts with `counter` at `1`.

Then it waits for the forked child process to finish.

(Whatever happens in the forked process, does not affect the parent's version of `counter`. Each process has its own memory space; no variables are shared.)

And, finally the `printf()` statement first increments `counter` with the `++` operator, this makes `counter` get the value `2`.